# Javascript: POST with AJAX instead of FETCH

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this script to upload a file via browser:

```
function onSubmit() {
    const url = 'uploadURl';
    fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: input.files[0]
        }).then(function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            location.reload();
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.error('Got error:', err);
        });
}
```

It works fine, but I would like to use `$.ajax` instead of `fetch`.
How can it be rewritten? In particular, I still did not get how to properly setup the request body for the file.

**Update:**

If I write:

```
$.post({
    url: 'uploadUrl',
    { data: input.files[0] }
})
.done(function() {
    console.log('File uploaded');
});
```

I get: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Comment: Show what you've tried please. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @RandyCasburn I just updated my post.

Comment: Good - simple change: remove the `{ }` surrounding your `data` property. ( should be `data: input.files[0]` )

Comment: May I ask _why_ you want to make this change?

Answer (score 0):

rewritten to use ajax would look something like this.

```
 $.post'uploadURI', {data: files.input[0]}, function(data, status) {
     //The first callback parameter holds the content of the page requested, and the second callback parameter holds the status of the request
   }};
```

Hope this helps. Ajax is a relatively simple to grasp. A quick look at the docs would probably help as well